# How to extract a encoded URL from a string using regex in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

This is what a typical string looks like

```
<img src="http://example.com/img/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffs02.androidpit.info%2Fblog%2Fx36%2F413336.jpg&width=540&mix=c5922-fAndroid">
```

I want it to become

```
<img src=https://fs02.androidpit.info/blog/x36/413336.jpg>
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: Don't know if this is enough for you? http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/fYT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$line = preg_replace_callback(
    '/(<img src=")[^\?]*.*\?url=([^&=]+).*(">)/i',
    function ($matches) {
        return $matches[1] . urldecode($matches[2]) . $matches[3];
    },
    '<img src="http://example.com/img/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffs02.androidpit.info%2Fblog%2Fx36%2F413336.jpg&width=540&mix=c5922-fAndroid">'
);
```

Comment: Thank you very much marv :).

Comment: From what I understand, the callback version uses a callback to return our string. and the regex is divided into three groups. While returning the final version, we encode the middle part which is our actual URL. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Just be careful with regular expression cause it is await that url parameter will be right after `?` symbol.